# Provisioning Profile "Team" is "Unknown"

Tags: ios, provisioning

Today I updated my Ad Hoc provisioning profile to include new devices using the developer provisioning portal.

The update went normally, but after downloading the updated profile, the "Team" field in XCode's Organizer shows "Unknown."  When building the profile cannot be found.

Any idea what's causing this "Unknown" team?  I opened the profile as a PList and see the team name is still included in the file itself.

Is anyone else having a similar issue today?

Answer (score 22):

For me it worked after opening the **Organizer** window on the Provisioning Tab, then clicking on the **Refresh button** (on the bottom right corner).

Comment: Where it is? Can you please make screenshots?

Comment: You can open the organizer from the menu bar : Window -> Organizer

Answer (score 2):

Since this answer is already a bit older but still shows up as a first result when searching for the Unknown Team issue: Make sure that your account has access to the certificates and identifiers as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674208/development-team-not-showing-in-xcode).

I also mentioned it in the comments of the mentioned post, but you eventually need to remove and add your account in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts after enabling & saving the certificates access on App Store Connect, so all the teams show up in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. Open Utilities > Keychain Access. You should see a bunch of private or public keys with nondescript metadata. Delete all of them and then go to Xcode's Organizer. Go to the Devices tab, select Provisioning Profiles from the Library and hit Refresh. The team should be defined in the latest profile.

Answer (score 1):

I had my personal iCloud account not connected to the account the profiles where signed to, so my account was not a member of the team/organization. After adding my personal account and a restart of Xcode, the team name showed up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with too many SSL certs confusing Xcode. See http://simianzombie.com/?p=2306.

Comment: Try to provide a bit more information in your answer than just a link. Links often change or become 404s.

Comment: "Answers" which do not even start to be useful without following their link are not helpful because links expire / go away / etc. Please edit your answer to contain at least a minimum of useful information here, and refer to the link for less necessary follow-up details if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check this answer also, not only was my team "unknown", but the organizer kept on crashing.

[Xcode crash when refreshing provisioning profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434296/xcode-crash-when-refreshing-provisioning-profiles)