# Renaming a Project Causing Provisioning Erros

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios-provisioning

I did a major restructuring of my app, and decided the easiest way to do this, was to create a new project with a new name.  After everything was working, I went in and renamed the project but now I get "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

I went into my app-info.plist and ensured that my CFBundleIdentifier is the same.  I confirmed that the Project Name is the same, and that the built app is the same.  I confirmed in my Build Settings that it shows my Distribution Profile.

This is the first time I've completely rewritten the app this way, is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning both projects? (cmd+shift+k)

Comment: Try one of these threads https://devforums.apple.com/message/796388#796388 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434296/xcode-crash-when-refreshing-provisioning-profiles