# Xcode 5 crashes when exporting a OS X application from an archive

Tags: macos, xcode5

I am just a member of the iOS Developer Program, not of the Mac Developer Program, so I can’t code sign my Mac applications.

I tried to rebuild an OS X App of mine with my fresh Xcode 5 installation. This only worked once completely, so I tried with an app template to see if it is related to my project. Problem persists:

- Create new Cocoa Application (no Core Data, not document-based)
- Leave build settings as they are (Don't Code Sign, PROVISIONING_PROFILE none)
- Archive
- Distribute
- Export as Application
- Result: "No Identities are available for signing”. No chance to continue without code signing.

Either

- Select "Import Developer Profile", then cancel  -> Crash

or

- Select "Download Identities", select the one that is shown (only iOS Development) -> Crash

There used to be an option for "Don't code sign" after selecting "Export as Application", but this is gone. But I am pretty sure I have seen this when I tried Xcode 5 for the first time three days before. I managed to build, archive and export my application without problems. But when I try it now on my iMac and my MacBook Pro, it doesn’t work.

I also tried to follow the hints from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434296/xcode-crash-when-refreshing-provisioning-profiles?rq=1), but to no avail.

Thanks for any help.