# Development team not showing in Xcode

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I am an self-employed iOS developer and so have my own iOS distribution membership.

For a few days, I am working as a developer in a team. My apple account has been added in their iTunes Connect / Users and Roles. It works since I can access to the app details of the current app we develop.

However, I can't get it right on Xcode. And so Xcode says the bundle ID is not right because I don't have the provisioning profiles.

In 'Project>General>Identity>Team', I can only select my own account and I don't see the new team I am part of.
I don't see it neither in the Accounts page of Xcode preferences.

A provisioning profile has been created by the team leader for me. It didn't solve the problem.

Question: How to add new team we belong to in Xcode?

---

## Note - at long last Apple will resolve this insanity,

## They are finally fixing it in 2018:

[image]

Comment: Incredibly, on Apple, there ***IS A DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 'DEVELOPER' AND 'ITUNES CONNECT' THINGS.***  Your company has to invite you on the "developer thing" as shown in images by @imbru below.  If you're "only" invited on the "itunes thing", you're screwed.  So stupid.

Answer (score 169):

## Apple has now unified both AppStore Connect and developer.apple.com systems.

To add profile & certificates capabilities:

- Navigate to [App Store Connect > Users and Access](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users)
- Select your user account. (You may need to be a team admin to do this.)
- In section "Developer Resources", check the box "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
  You will only see this option when your dev account is a 'Organization'

---

*Update: This answer posted in February 2019 is still valid as of September 2021*

> [image: developer resources section]

> [image]

Comment: I'm trying to add someone as an App Manager, when I scroll down to this checkbox it is `unchecked` and greyed out not allowing me to check the box. Any idea why?

Comment: @Wikkle_A the checkbox looked disabled to me, but clicking in it worked. The click target is super small though, and clicking the label doesn't work.

Comment: So we found out that I didn't have permissions for certificates on the client account. Under the User tab there is  now a checkbox to allow permissions for certificates that can only be given by people who have permissions of certificates.

Comment: This option appears to be completely disabled if you have an "Individual" developer account instead of an "Organization" developer account. Even if I hack into the HTML and forcefully check the checkbox, when I try to save the changes, I get an error that says "Your account doesn't have permission to edit other users. Contact your team agent for more information." For the record, I'm the account owner/admin, so I should have access to everything. More info: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/358562/13594

Comment: This is the current solution under the unified systems. The accepted answer is outdated.

Comment: Thanks, ticking those "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" box and clicking "Save" did the trick.

Comment: You don't want your developers creating certs because that will destroy a pipeline from signing. xCode should have access to the Team to download the individual permission to debug the device

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me - it was just not directly refreshed for me in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts in the Teams table after saving it on App Store Connect. I just removed and added my account and then all teams were there - just in case someone else has this issue maybe.

Comment: @Hugo probably you can update the date mentioning as of 2021 this answer works

Comment: Adding to Mitemmetim's comment...adding then deleting initially didn't work. Done again a few minutes later and the re-add led to the Team display.

Comment: So what if I've an individual account, what shall I do then to add other developer to work on my project

Comment: Shorter question & answer (2023) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141336/xcode-developer-team-not-showing-in-xcode-flutter

Answer (score 95):

## Overwhelming issue here:

Apple have two *totally different* fundamental systems,

## - the "developer.apple" system

and the

## - iTunes connect system

They are completely different.  As a rule you **need to be in both**.

It's the single most confusing (and ridiculous) thing in the whole software industry. It is a source of endless confusion.

When you suffer the problem on this page, 99% of the time the solution is "they added me on iTunes Connect, but they forgot to add me on Developer..." or "they forgot to make me an admin on one or the other."

---

If you are added to a existing team, Ask for an invitation as **Admin**

Go in apple developer center: https://developer.apple.com/account

**Again, that's developer.apple,**

## NOT

**itunesconnect.apple !!!**

Once you are in at developer.apple.com/account, be sure you are in the correct team on the top right corner:

[image]

Go in section people

[image]
[image]

Be sure your are admin :

[image]

If everything it's ok here. So stop completelly Xcode and restart it.

Be sure your account is added to Xcode in Preference->Account

[image]

If not, click on the + on the bottom left corner and add your account.

Now, in your project, go on your target :

[image]

And in team, your new team must appear :

[image]

To repeat,

## on Apple, there IS A DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 'DEVELOPER' AND 'ITUNES CONNECT' THINGS.

Your company has to invite you on the "developer thing" as shown in the images here. If you're "only" invited on the "itunes thing", nothing works. Really silly and bizarre, but that's how it is.

Comment: Thanks! 'stop completely XCode and restart it.' - solved the issuse for me

Comment: This was the actual solution for me. My account wasn't added to developer.apple.com yet. After that + installing the required certificates and keys I was able to build and upload the app.

Comment: This was really helpful as I was confused. Apple should make some little tutorial videos like the Android team. Android is being more fun to develop for recently.

Comment: Also remember that you can only invite people if you have a company. If your account is registered as an individual developer you will not even see the People button.

Comment: THIS IS OUT OF DATE. Please see the answer by Hugo Dozois.

Comment: @kevin probably you should update this answer

Answer (score 36):

Xcode does not see your development team(it is not a personal team) until admin **check in** the next setting in [AppStoreConnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users/) even if your role is **Developer**

> Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

Comment: It works, App manager can do it too though.

Comment: As an App Manager, i need access to this area. I can't, the admin did not allow it specifically.

Comment: Confirmed, this is definitely what fixes the issue, and yes you'll need the team admin to do it.

Answer (score 16):

SOLUTION : My account was not added in the certificates page of the member center of the development team leader.
He just added me and I received an invitation to join. It solved the problem since I can now select my team in Xcode.

Comment: Do you mean the https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/ page? I have the same problem but can't find where you would add certificates for an different account.

Comment: In fact, you don't have to add certificates for a different account at any time at the condition of setting up properly iTunes Connect, which is not easy at all ! I don't exactly know which page to go since it is my team leader who did it.

Answer (score 6):

In addition of what @opyh said, your user must have checked the option "Access to certificates, identifiers and profiles." in https://itunesconnect.apple.com/access/users to see your own team.

After that, you have to add your account in xcode > target > team, and you will show your user is assigned to a team.

Answer (score 6):

For those who live in 2021 but are simply lost, here is where the "Team" button moved !

You’ll simply find it under the section “Signing and Capabilities” instead of “Main”. See the image below:

[image: TEAM BUTTON MOVED IN “SIGNING AND CAPABILITIES”]

Comment: Please add all informaiton to your answer instead of linking to images

Comment: Last version of July 2020

Comment: Shannah shows here as a (Personal Team), but a personal team can't archive a ipa, so this allows you to test on simulators, but not act as an "xcode developer" who can create ipas.

Comment: what do i have to do to archive IPA since I'm on personal team?

Answer (score 4):

If you are already given access to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`, but you don't see your team in Xcode or can't open `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` section in `AppStoreConnect`, just **wait**. Waiting for **1 hour** and 1 day worked for me in two cases.

It seems that Apple has unified `AppStoreConnect` with `Developer Portal` using async messaging mechanism - something like Kafka. `Developer Portal` get's updated with a delay.

Comment: Unbelievable! In the morning, everything seemed to be working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems when Apple merged App Store Connect and Developer accounts, some accounts have been missed, like mine – In my case (I am part of a team, but not the account holder), I had to use a different solution:

- Check if your team shows up on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com (as entry in the menu in the top right corner)
- Check if your team shows up on https://developer.apple.com/account (as entry in the menu in the top right corner)

If the team is missing in one of the menus, let the account owner remove your membership in App Store Connect and re-invite you. After accepting your new invitation, the missing team should be displayed on both App Store Connect and the Developer portal. Now you can also use it in Xcode.

Comment: I have no idea, why it was neccessary but removing and adding my account again helped. thx!

Answer (score 3):

I faced into the same issue, after 1 hour trying many ways, they showed `your developer program was expired` :D. Why don't it show at the first time to save my time.

Comment: same here, why don't they just show it in the first place

Answer (score 2):

For this you have to do following things:

1. Check whether your apple ID is added into the team on Apple
   Developer portal with specific role. If not then it should be added.
2. After that you have to add your apple account in the
   settings of the Xcode at following path. If added then remove and add again

> Xcode -> Preferences ->
>       Accounts -> Add the account by clicking on 'Plus' (+) button on the
>       left botttom section

If this is done and still have a issue then regenerate the provisioning profile, install and use it.

Comment: 1. My apple ID has been added with a specific role since I can manage the app on iTunes connect. 2. My account is already into xCode since I already have uploaded app from this account directly from xCode. I have received a .mobileprovision and double-clicked it but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else worked for you, pay attention to your team type.

An Individual team can have other team members but they are restricted to App Store Connect operations. It can’t have other developers.

[Program Roles documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) calls this out:

> Note: If you’re enrolled as an individual and add users in App Store
> Connect, users receive access only to your content in App Store
> Connect and are not considered part of your team in the Apple
> Developer Program.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need the appropriate certificate. without the  need to have full access to certifications or to be full admin

you can email the creator of the signing certificate. Ask the creator to export the signing certificate on their Mac so you can install it on your Mac.
[image]

Please see the link below for more information:

- Apple's documentation of what app signing is
  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8
- Apple's documentation on how to "Create, export, and delete signing certificates"
  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to go build settings under Signing -> Code signing identity then changed it to iOS Developer and went under Development team -> select others then add the team key.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I needed my admin to additionally grant me 'Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'. The solution was given here by user bruno887 https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117098

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day of unsuccessful attempts, one colleague told me how to fix it

Make sure that your apple id has access to certificates, it is shown as an enabled checkbox at the inscription "✔️ Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" (left red arrow on screenshot) the role of "Admin" has this privilege by default

If after you have been added to the team, taking into account access to certificates, you still do not see your development team in the xcode settings, try the following:

❗️ Switch "**Preferred Currency**" to any other (right blue arrow on screenshot) -> click the **SAVE** button in the upper right corner and refresh the *accounts page* in the *xcode settings*, your command should appear immediately

[AppStore Connect Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YafUs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you recently signed into the account, ensured you have the correct permissions in Apple Developer + App Store Connect, and still can't get a new team to show up, I've **had to restart my computer or log out / log in** order to get it to appear. Sounds crazy but this has been the only resolution for me on multiple occasions.

Comment: It does not sound crazy, it shows you are experienced on the Apple platform :^)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the user in App Store Connect, Mac Settings, and re-login the user that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason for the development team not showing in xCode is the developer account bank payment issue. Due to that, my account services have been suspended.
[Here is a screenshot of the warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv2mw.png)

Comment: Could you try to rephrase and make your answer clearer so people can understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason of the problem was that the project owner wasn't inviting me as an Organization (but as an Individual)

[On developer.apple.com it says:](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-your-team/add-and-edit-users/)

> If you’re enrolled in the Apple Developer Program as an individual,
> you can give up to 50 additional users access to your content in App
> Store Connect. All users receive access only to App Store Connect and
> aren't considered part of your team in the Apple Developer Program,
> and they won't receive access to other membership resources or
> benefits.