# Same bundle identifiers

Tags: xcode

This is the first time I am working with a remote team. The team added me to their existing apple developer account as a **member**. My apple id is non paid developer account. Now, I am trying to install a project on my device using the bundle identifier and provisioning profile from the developer account. The bundle identifier & provisioning profile was already there, I did not create new. The app build successfully, no conflict but it do not install on device, before running on device xcode throws this:

> This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique.

Do I need a new bundle identifier & provisioning profile to run on device ? What happen if two team member use the same bundle identifier & provisioning profile ? Note that this project got push notification enabled in the provisioning profile. Is there any possibility with the pods ?

Comment: i think you have to change your team in xcode project setting. select the team in which your project is created

Comment: Selected team from the beginning, does not work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my case I solved the issue by changing my application bundle identifier & extension bundle identifier. If application bundle identifier is like : **com.companyName.productName** then the extension bundle identifier has to be like : **com.companyName.productName.extensionName**

Comment: I am using one signal extension. If i kept the same bundle id then notification will work in debug mode but getting the error in release mode `This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique.` Also if i change the bundle id of both then i got one signal error `Bundle mismatch error`. Any help?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works for me

Answer (score 17):

[image: check the image and try this.]

just Check the option
it will be work. :)

project targets > Build Phases > Embaded app extension

Comment: Can you explain more? Why is it working? What does it means?

Comment: This approach worked. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when multiple frameworks or bundles have the same Bundle ID.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
For me running `flutter clean && flutter run` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

There are some options. First one, is to change the bundle identifier to whatever. this will allow you to install the app on your phone without any changes although you could not release any app for your team on the app-store. the second option is to ask for developer account from your team. there would not be any big problem it 2 person login from one developer account in XCode as I know.
To login as a team member, your team needs to add your apple-id to the team.
If you are using push notifications, you won't receive them if you change the bundle id. and you have to ask your team to add you as a team member

Comment: They have already added me as a team member, now my account is developer account. Tried your methods few times, still its not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674208/development-team-not-showing-in-xcode
check this link, maybe it could help you, I think your team didn't added you in a right way. there are some confusions in adding somebody as a team member.

Comment: They have added and I could select team from my xcode, so I think thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean the project(to delete the Products/xxx.ipa file). In my case,I had modify the Info.plist in the xxx.ipa for debug reson.And this caurse the error "This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique."