# Xcode: Developer Team not showing in Xcode || Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-developer-account

I have permission of Develper / App manager / Admin but in xcode all roles are not showing.
I tried to find out on every platform but the right answer is not there.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so here I found the solution.

i share us above image Under section "ADDITIONAL RESOURCES"

-> You need to have compulsory 4 permission to fix it.

1. access to reports
2. Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles ( MOST IMPORTANT)
3. Access to Could Managed Distribution Certificate
4. Create Apps

> ** Addtional remove account from xcode and re add if need ( not shwing )

> if uncheck in sign in capabilities and check it again and choose auto.

[image]

Comment: Yes , facing same issue and requesting additional permissions will resolve it. Thanks you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved like this;

Actually, I authorized myself by thinking of it as an organization account, and tried to sign with my own account. However, individual accounts can only be signed by the account holder.

If you pay attention to this, maybe it will help.