Team is not showing in Xcode
I got an invite from an individual apple account and I have been added. now this account is being showing on my developer account but when I come to Xcode it is not showing. can anyone helps this out...
here in the additional resources of that individual account it is showing generate api key instead of Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles is those are same? or any new update?
can any one help me out

May be check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168851/833395,  Your inviter should tick the checkbox for certificates and identifiers.

Go to Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts -> Tap on + to add account.
After this the teams should show on your XCode.

you are saying that I need to add the client Apple ID as manually in my Xcode?
my concern Is this account is already showing in my Apple Store connect but not in my Xcode.?!

I guess yes. Looks like account is not configured on xcode. Can you try the steps and post if it solves the problem

I will try and let you know. but still it is showing in my Apple Store connect it won't come as default in my team on Xcode for signing and capabilities?
